# How to access array or variable inside main method from other method?

Tags: java, variables, methods, program-entry-point

So at first I made my code inside main method, and I want to divide it into several void methods to make it neat. But here is my problem, some of the variable I declared inside main method, not as instance variable. How to solve this?

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    String[] allcars = args;

    String[] car1 = allCars[0].split("(?!^)");
    String[] car2 = allCars[1].split("(?!^)");

    String[] tire = {car1[0], car2[0]};
    String[] color = {car1[1], car2[1]};

public static void myMethod(){
    for (int i = 0; i <= tire.length-2; i++){
        for (int j = i+1; j < tire.length; j++){
            if ((tire[i]).equals(tire[j])){
                value += 2;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It gives me error tire cannot be resolved to a variable

Comment: Please tag the programming language you intended.

Comment: If it's Java I'm pretty sure you can't do that - atleast that's how local variables work. You have few options though - like passing these variables as arguments to your other methods or of course, as you said, declare them as instance/class variables.

Comment: yes it is java. So I need to pass argument to my method if I want to use that variable? I can't declare it as instance variable because there is a lot of calculation and function at main method until I get tire[] array

Answer (score 0):

Function parameteres are used for such things. Look an example

```
public static void myMethod(String[] tire);

public static void main(String[] args){

    String[] allcars = args;

    String[] car1 = allCars[0].split("(?!^)");
    String[] car2 = allCars[1].split("(?!^)");

    String[] tire = {car1[0], car2[0]};
    String[] color = {car1[1], car2[1]};

    myMethod(tire);
}
```

BTW, your code has syntax error - you forgot to close `main` function block brace.